# Is there any way to call clean up function that also cleans the native code while leaving any activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, c, android-activity, android-ndk

see

i have `mainActivity` which calls `tempActivity`

Now inside tempActivity i call some native method and malloc some data .. so now when user

1>  come back from tempActivity to mainActivity or

2> exit from whole application

i need to call one clean up function which free all data malloc in native method so how can i implement such things?

Does android framework has any method to handle such clean up function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i think the question is about how to free the memory that is being allocated using `malloc()` inside native code.

I had the same requirement in one of my Projects. I did it in the following way.

Inside `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`, I did a native call, which I have used to `free()` the allocated memory. This I think is the best and simplest way to do that. I am not sure if android is providing some API,s for this. It would be informatory to know if something like this exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the diagram taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

[image]

Basically the `Activity` class is defining several methods that can be of use to you:

- `onPause` which is called every time your activity is paused: that is your screen locks, you go to other activity
- `onDestroy` and `onStop` called when you go to other activity.

Maybe some of these methods will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the transition from `tempActivity` to `mainActivity`, put a call to the clean up function in `tempActivity`'s `onDestroy` method.
2. For the case where the entire application is exited: that is much more messy. There is no global function that tells when an app exits, so you'll need to use some other means of tracking that the application is exiting.

I'd recommend using a `Service` with the `onStartCommand` function set to use `START_NOT_STICKY` and then in the `onDestroy` method of the `Service` call the clean up function. If you do this and you have all `Activity`s use the service then you can do it all in there.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended technique is to allocate whatever you need in `onResume` and clean up in `onPause`. This way you allocate when your activity is about to be shown and clean up when your activity has become partially or fully obscured by some other activity.

Comment: These two does not map correctly together. I mean that `onResume` can be called after `onPause` without passing through `onStop` thus making you allocate twice without freeing the resources. Maybe you will need to correct this in your answer.